# Image smoothing problems in C

Tags: c, matrix, smoothing

ok so i'm trying to write an image smoothing program using integers with a mean filter. For some reason though only the corner sections, and the top, bottom sections are out putting correctly.

for example a number with four neighbors should return the average of those 4 neighbors, instead it is not. A number with 3 neighbors should return the average of those 3 neighbors.

this though is only working for corner values and top bottom values. The sides and the middle are not calculating correctly.

```
please enter number of columns and rows
5 5
 1  83  92  66  38
87  27  98  36  80
54  55  33  97   5
26  93  40  79  55
21  34  54  85  25
The smoothed image is
85  40  82  55  73
14  89  51  81  20
71  38  83  24  76
73  40  68  64  52
30  56  53  52  70
```

as you can see the 1 in the first matrix has 83 and 87 as its neighbors and returns 85 correctly in the 2nd matrix, the second number 87 has 1,27,54 as its neighbors but incorrectly returns 14 as the average. Can someone take a look at my code below and please fix this with either an edit, or detailed instructions, I've been looking at this for hours and can't seem to understand the problem. I will be eternally grateful if you can fix this!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
// function that randomly generates numbers 
void fillArray(int a[10][20], int m, int n)
{
 int random;
  int i,j;  
      for (i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
          for (j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
              random=rand()%100;
              a[i][j]=random;
          }
      }
 }
// function that prints the first matrix of random numbers
void printarray (int a[10][20], int m, int n)
{
 int i,j;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
// function that finds the mean for any number and its 4 nieghbors 
void corner1 (int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int n, int m)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if (i<=0&&j<=0){
           c[i][j]=(a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/2;
          }
      }
  }
}
void middle(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int n, int m)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m-1;i++) 
{
    for (j=1;j<n-1;j++)
    {

        c[i][j]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/4;
    }
}

}

void side1 (int a[10][20],int c[10][20], int n, int m)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m-1;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
      if (i>=1&&j<=0){

              c[i][j]=(0+0+a[i-1][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/3; 
        } 
    }     
 }
}  
void corner2(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {

        if (i>=1 && j>=0){

           c[i][j]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j+1])/2;
        }
    }
 }
}               
void top (int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=1;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        c[i][j]=(a[i][j-1]+a[i][j+1]+a[i+1][j])/3;
          }
    }
}


void bottom (int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        c[i][j]=(a[i][j-1]+a[i-1][j]+a[i][j+1])/3;
    }
  }   
}
void side2(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
{
   int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m-1;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      c[i][n-1]=(0+0+a[i-1][j]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j-1])/3;        
    }         
  } 
}     


void corner3(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        c[i][n-1]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1])/2;
        }
   }
} 
void corner4(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
{
int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<m-1;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        c[i][n-1]=(a[i+1][j]+a[i][j-1])/2;
    }
  }
}                             
int main()
{

int a[10][20];
int c[10][20];
int m,n;
srand(time(NULL));
//User input
printf("please enter number of columns and rows\n");
scanf("%d %d", &m,&n);
fillArray(a,m,n);
printarray (a,m,n);
printf("The smoothed image is\n");



corner1(a,c,m,n);
side1(a,c,m,n);
middle (a,c,m,n);
corner2(a,c,m,n);
top(a,c,m,n);
bottom(a,c,m,n);
side2(a,c,m,n);
corner3(a,c,m,n);
corner4(a,c,m,n);
printarray(c,m,n);

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JTA haha Thank you. Now if you could fix my issue I'm having, you'll be my new best friend

Answer (score 1):

Welp, it would seem that we're in the same class, because I'm currently working on the same project (and I saw your earlier question where you quoted his assignment PDF word-for-word). I haven't finished it yet, but I know one problem is that you're setting it up completely wrong and using way too many functions. It should be one smoothening function with a bunch of if statements. Again, I haven't finished it yet, so I don't have any code to show you, but when I do I'll either edit this post if it's possible (EDIT: it's possible, so that's what I'll do).

edit: Alright, so I finally finished it. Freaking took me forever to realize that I was making the boundaries one space too big. Instead of posting the entire code, I'll just post the single smoothening function that should be used.

```
int smoothen(int mArray[100][100], int uX, int uY)  {

int tempArr[100][100];
int x, y;

for(x = 0; x < uX; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < uY; y++)
    {
        // Multiple if/else statements to test pixel location
        if ((x == 0) && (y == 0))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x+1][y] + mArray[x][y+1]) / 3;
        }
        else if ((x > 0 && x < uX-1) && (y == 0))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x+1][y] + mArray[x-1][y] + mArray[x][y+1]) / 4;
        }
        else if ((x == uX-1) && (y == 0))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x-1][y] + mArray[x][y+1]) / 3;
        }
        else if ((x == uX-1) && (y > 0 && y < uY-1))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x-1][y] + mArray[x][y+1] + mArray[x][y-1]) / 4;
        }
        else if ((x == uX-1) && (y == uY-1))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x-1][y] + mArray[x][y-1]) / 3;
        }
        else if ((x > 0 && x < uX-1) && (y == uY-1))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x+1][y] + mArray[x-1][y] + mArray[x][y-1]) / 4;
        }
        else if ((x == 0) && (y == uY-1))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x+1][y] + mArray[x][y-1]) / 3;
        }
        else if ((x == 0) && (y > 0 && y < uY-1))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x+1][y] + mArray[x][y+1] + mArray[x][y-1]) / 4;
        }
        else if ((x > 0 && x < uX-1) && (y > 0 && y < uY-1))
        {
            tempArr[x][y] = (mArray[x][y] + mArray[x+1][y] + mArray[x-1][y] + mArray[x][y+1] + mArray[x][y-1]) / 5;
        }

    }
}
printArray(tempArr, uX, uY);  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the dimensions switched in some functions:

```
void middle(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int n, int m)
...
void side1 (int a[10][20],int c[10][20], int n, int m)
...
void corner2(int a[10][20], int c[10][20], int m, int n)
```

Comment: Hmmm...I didn't notice that, and while helpful, it still has not fixed my problem. This is driving me insane.